# ANTLR4 does not find grammar on import

Tags: java, parsing, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to split my ANTLR4 grammar in multiple files so i can test them more easily, i am using gradle as a build tool in a java project.

Both grammar compile correctly by separate but when i add the import to my main grammar i get the next compilation error

> error(110): kanekotic/specflow/rider/SpecflowFeature.g4:3:7: can't find or load grammar SpecflowScenario

the `inherited` grammar looks like:

```
grammar SpecflowScenario;

@header {
    package kanekotic.specflow.rider;
}

scenario
    : 'Scenario: ';
```

and the `main` grammar looks like:

```
grammar SpecflowFeature;

import SpecflowScenario;

@header {
    package kanekotic.specflow.rider;
}

file returns [List<String> values]
    @init { $values = new ArrayList<String>(); }
    : 'Feature: ' EOF;
```

What am i doing wrong? is this not allowed?

edit:

the `gradle.build` looks like:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.1.10"
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

intellij {
    version '143.2370.31'
    pluginName 'Specflow Rider'
}

group 'kanekotic.specflow.rider'
version '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
}
```

all the code as it is open sourced is in this next link: https://github.com/kanekotic/Specflow.Rider/tree/antlr4_multiple_grammar

Comment: Do you have the grammar in the file `SpecflowScenario.g4` in the same folder? Maybe also post the part of your gradle file.

Comment: @user3151902 thanks for your response, yes they are at the same directory and my gradle you can see on the edit. also added the repo as its open source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Antlr plugin uses `src/main/antlr` as *lib* directory by default. As the grammar file to include is in `kanekotic/specflow/rider`, use the following code in your gradle file to include this location:

```
generateGrammarSource {
    arguments << "-lib" << "src/main/antlr/kanekotic/specflow/rider"
}
```

See also [this gradle thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-gradle-2-10s-antlr-plugin-to-import-an-antlr-4-lexer-grammar-into-another-grammar/14970/6).

Comment: thanks for actually pointing me towards the solution. I will accept it with a small change due files are not in `src/main/antlr` but in `'src/main/antlr/kanekotic/specflow/rider'` so probably the answer should be `'src/main/antlr/<grammar path>'`, and also I believe that `src/main/antlr` is the default lib path as if moved to the root it actually worked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I edited my answer accordingly.