# antlr4 import maven eclipse combination does not work can't find or load grammar

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, antlr4

With

- ANTLR 4.7
- ANTLR 4.7 maven plugin
- Eclipse Neon 4.6.2

i am trying to use the grammar import feature of ANTLR4.
see

- https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr

with the example iri grammar
https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/com/bitplan/iri

That grammar is basically the attempt to split the  https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/iri/IRI.g4 into three parts:

1. parser
2. lexer
3. imported basic lexer parts

At this point I am getting the error message:

`can't find or load grammar LexBasic`

I checked

- [ANTLR4 does not find grammar on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025605/antlr4-does-not-find-grammar-on-import)
- [Antlr4 import of combined grammar failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479217/antlr4-import-of-combined-grammar-failing)

and filed a bug report with
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2061

and wrote a wiki article at:
http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/ANTLR_maven_plugin

I then put the LexBasic.g4  file into the src/main/antlr4/imports directory and 
the error persisted. Only when i put LexBasic.g4 into src/main/antlr4
on the command line things would work nicely. But that seems to be different then what the documentation at http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/ says.

In 
https://gist.github.com/sharwell/4979017
I found a comment that the build-helper maven plugin is not needed any more. I'll still have to try this.

During my trials of the last few days I had lots of quirks with different pom.xml configurations. I would get error messages like:

- `can't find or load grammar LexBasic`
- `reference to undefined rule`

or the eclipse environment would start regenerating the java source files from the .g4 files in a non ending loop. I would have to call maven build from the menu to stop such a loop.

I am still not sure what the correct way to setup a project with parser lexer and imported lexer file would be using antlr4, maven and eclipse.

- **What would be the right way to set this up?**
- **Where can I find an example project?**

Answer (score 1):

@Wolfgang, I'm actually in the middle of a similar task right now.  I didn't know about the imports option.  Thanks for that.  By using the Maven configuration as referenced here in [Antlr4 maven plugin cannot find grammar files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089494/antlr4-maven-plugin-cannot-find-grammar-files-in-different-directories), I was able to get everything compiled with as much success as using the import statement.  However, I think the issue is with ANTLR4 IDE plugin itself.  The grammars compile, but Eclipse should recognize the import.  Also check out Sam's comments in the above post.  I know he has been a contributor to ANTLR and his insight is sound:  perhaps what I (and you) am trying to do is not worth the effort.  I'll let you know what else I find.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with ANTLR 4.7, ANTLR v4 Maven Plugin, ANTLR 4 IDE Eclipse Plugin, and Eclipse Oxygen.

If you see the error message `can't find or load grammar` in the problems view of Eclipse, it comes from the *ANTLR 4 IDE* Eclipse Plugin. So if you followed the guidelines of the [antlr4 maven documentation](http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/) (e.g. you put your grammar/lexer files under the `src/main/antlr4` directory), that's fine and your maven project should compile without errors. As I understand it from your question, this is the case for you too. To get rid of the error message of the eclipse plugin I also needed to add the same directory as a source directory to my project (i.e., go to `project settings/Java Build Path/(Source tab)`, and add e.g. the folder of `src/main/antlr4/.../(YourGrammar.g)` to the source folders.

**Update**

I tried to compile your github repo, and your pom seemed to be fine regardless some missing dependencies. I also noticed that you use `org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer` in the example which is not available since antlr 4.5.1, so you either use an earlier antlr version (e.g. 4.5), or uncomment this code. I created a pull request for you, so you can see my changes.

One other notice (while I was playing with your project) is that the antlr4ide plugin will generate the LexBasic.g4 lexer every small change in each grammar file (depending on it) which seems to be annoying. I would recommend deactivating the tool in the project settings (`ANTLR4/Tool`). You will compile the project through maven anyway. So you can still use the basic features of antlr4ide (e.g. syntax highlight, indexing) for the project but it will not re-generate the grammar for every small change.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Your setup is similar to mine. The main issue is still the possible endless loop which I can't figure out the reason for.

Comment: this 'endless loop' sounded interesting, so I took a closer look at your project. see what I found in my updated response.